# Setting Symbology for a Feature Class

Tags: arcpy, symbology, error-000732

I'm trying to automate a map, and one of those tasks is to set a specific symbology for a feature class. I create the feature class of Subject and Comps in the code, then add it to the map, then when I try to add the symbology created previously, it gives me an error

ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset C:\ArcMap\Res_Parcels.gdb\Subject does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (ApplySymbologyFromLayer)

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Set layer to apply symbology to
inputLayer1 = "C:\ArcMap\Res_Boulder.gdb\Subject"
inputLayer2 = "C:\ArcMap\Res_Boulder.gdb\Comps"
# Set layer that output symbology will be based on
symbologyLayer1 = "C:\ArcMap\Comps.lyr"
symbologyLayer2 = "C:\ArcMap\Subject.lyr"
# Apply the symbology from the symbology layer to the input layer
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (inputLayer1, symbologyLayer1)
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (inputLayer2, symbologyLayer2)
```

Comment: You're trying to apply symbology to a feature class, not a layer. You'll need to find the layer in your mxd with code such as `arcpy.mapping.ListLayers`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is having trouble finding the files.

I use double backslash to get to my files.
"C:\\ArcMap\\Res_Boulder.gdb\\Subject"

See this reference which shows the valid and invalid path options
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/setting-paths-to-data.htm

Answer (score 0):

Emil's comment assisted me with finding an answer. My code has me create a layer based on a selection, so using that layer, and pre-setting up a .lyr with the symbology I wanted, I was able to make it work.

```
sym = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Subject", df)[0]
sym1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Comps", df)[0]

# Set layer that output symbology will be based on
symbologyLayer1 = r'C:\ArcMap\Comps.lyr'
symbologyLayer2 = r'C:\ArcMap\Subject.lyr'
# Apply the symbology from the symbology layer to the input layer
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(sym, symbologyLayer2)
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(sym1, symbologyLayer1)
```